# How can I migrate a relational database for nosql?

Tags: mongodb, data-migration, nosql

I have an oracle database with a bunch of data that i need to migrate to a noSQL enviroment(i'm using MongoDB). Is there any tool to do that?

Comment: The way you model a document database is very different from an RDBMS, like Oracle. More importantly, the data access patterns are extremely different. There are no joins in MongoDb for example.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question as stated.... there are tools you can use... listing them, with pro's and con's would have been a useful (set of) answer(s). Someone may not like pot as a medicine, for example, but ppl use it, and it works in some cases... get over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiredPrairie is right. You can definitely write a tool to export your Oracle data straight to Mongo, but that is unwise.

Your Oracle data is most likely normalized and Mongo deals with *denormalized* data.

I know MongoVUE can import data from a relational database (http://www.mongovue.com/), but again, a straight import would be a headache.

Some steps for moving from one to the other:

1. Design the objects/documents you want in Mongo. Objects that will map closely to your application objects. For example, an Animals object/document. What fields do you need?
2. Write queries in Oracle that produce a fully realized Animal. In Oracle you might have tables called AnimalType, Animal, AnimalInfo, etc. You want to join them all to produce one big Animal object.
3. Write a tool to pump data from (2) to (1). For example, if you need three stored procedures or queries to make an Animal object, your code will run those procedures, make an object in whatever language, serialize that object to JSON and then write to Mongo.

Comment: thanks ryan i will take your tips to do what i need :)